# For loop executes only once

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have hard times with implementation of this script. Have no idea why it iterates only once, when it "should" at least 3. I have found some similar problems on SO so I guess i dont understand something. When `IF !ERRORLEVEL! equ 0` condition is fulfilled it prints and `echo` and exits script and my expected behavior is to iterate 2 more times. Does someone know the reason and could help me with this a little?

```
set "modules=Module1 Module2 Module3"

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%i in (%modules%) do (
    set moduleName=%%i
    @echo Running !moduleName! module...
    set "moduleBootRunName=!moduleName:~6,1!"
    call :tolower moduleBootRunName
    set "moduleBootRunName=!moduleBootRunName!!moduleName:~7!"
    copy NUL > %logsTmpFile%\!moduleName!.txt
    start cmd /c "gradlew :modules:!moduleBootRunName!:bootRun --info > %logsTmpFile%\!moduleName!.txt"
    :waitForModule
    findstr /c:"Started !moduleName!" %logsTmpFile%\!moduleName!.txt > NUL
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! equ 0 (
        @echo Started !moduleName!
    ) ELSE (
        @echo Waiting for !moduleName!...
        timeout /t 5 > NUL
        goto waitForModule
    )
)
exit /b
:tolower
for %%L IN (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) DO SET %1=!%1:%%L=%%L!
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Labels don't work properly inside (code blocks)  Put that part into a sub. BTW to extract the last pos from a var you can use `!var:~-1!` And why do you extract a number and try to lowercase it? Proper indenting makes your better readable.

Comment: I would suggest trying to restructure your script such that you don't have a label inside the `For` loop.

Comment: how can I do that? Because I need that `timeout` in loop. @LotPings what is `sub`?

Comment: Exactly as you call your `:tolower` put the code from `:waitForModule` upto the closing parentheses of the ELSE to the end and call it from inside the `for %%I`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested

```
set "modules=Module1 Module2 Module3"

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%i in (%modules%) do (
    set moduleName=%%i
    @echo Running !moduleName! module...
    set "moduleBootRunName=!moduleName:~6,1!"
    call :tolower moduleBootRunName
    set "moduleBootRunName=!moduleBootRunName!!moduleName:~7!"
    copy NUL > %logsTmpFile%\!moduleName!.txt
    start cmd /c "gradlew :modules:!moduleBootRunName!:bootRun --info > %logsTmpFile%\!moduleName!.txt"
    call :waitForModule
)
exit /b

:tolower
for %%L IN (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) DO SET %1=!%1:%%L=%%L!
goto :EOF

:waitForModule
findstr /c:"Started !moduleName!" %logsTmpFile%\!moduleName!.txt > NUL
IF !ERRORLEVEL! equ 0 (
    @echo Started !moduleName!
) ELSE (
    @echo Waiting for !moduleName!...
    timeout /t 5 > NUL
    goto waitForModule
)
```